# how can allow user if is login with auth0

Tags: react-redux, next.js, auth0

I am using Auth0 for my authentication and Redux for my state management, I want the user can only add favorite coin if is login else it should redirect the user to login.

Here's my code

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToBasket } from "../slices/basketSlice";
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

function FullCryptoListComponent (){

    const { user } = useUser();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const addItemToBasket = () => {
        dispatch(
          addToBasket({
            id,
            name,
            price,
            marketCapDaily,
            marketCap,
            rank,
            image,
            percent,
            coinSymbol
          })
        );
        
      };

  return (
<div>
 <StarBorderIcon onClick={user? ({addItemToBasket}): (<a href="/api/auth/login" />)} className="absolute top-3 right-0 lg:relative lg:top-0 lg:right-0 cursor-pointer" />
</div>
)
}
export default FullCryptoListComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find if a user is logged-in and authenticated (isAuthenticated) field;

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

  const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();
```

then allow the user to "add favorite coin" only if `isAuthenticated` is true